# Flutter ListTile - Vertical align all items to center

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, listtile

I want to align everything inside the ListTile (title, subtitle, leading, trailing etc) vertically to center. What's the best way to do it?

```
const Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 20),
    child: Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: FlutterLogo(size: 55),
        title: Text('Overview'),
        subtitle: Text(
          '250.956.261',
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_right_outlined,
          size: 30,
        ),
        isThreeLine: true,
      ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially misunderstood your question to be about horizontally centering the contents of the `ListTile`. To center the items vertically inside of the card, you might only need to disable the `isThreeLine` parameter. Disabling it causes the contents to be centered vertically.

Code for build method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: FlutterLogo(size: 55),
          title: Text('Overview'),
          subtitle: Text(
            '250.956.261',
          ),
          trailing: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_right_outlined,
            size: 30,
          ),
          // isThreeLine: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Such a simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternative code below to get what you want

```
         Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 20),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const FlutterLogo(size: 55),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text('Overview'),
                          Text(
                            '250.956.261',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
               const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_right_outlined,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Thank for your time! Although just removing the "isThreeLine: true" did it as mentioned by the @KGEM